# cannot ping localhost

Tags: 14.04, ip, localhost, ping, ifconfig

I am not able to ping localhost

```
  ashish@ashishk:~$ ping localhost
    PING localhost (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
    ^C
    --- localhost ping statistics ---
    16 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 15003ms
```

Here is my host file :

```
ashish@ashishk:~/chef-repo/.chef$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost
115.112.95.170    ashishk.example.com chef

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Comment: Can you `ping 127.0.0.1`?

Comment: No.  Can't ping 127.0.0.1 also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got solution :

ashish@ashishk:~/chef-repo/.chef$ vim /etc/sysctl.conf

```
# Ignore Directed pings
net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_all = 1
```

made it 0 it worked